# Replace sequence of chars in string with its length

Tags: python, regex, string

Say I have the following string:

```
mystr = "6374696f6e20????28??????2c??2c????29"
```

And I want to replace every sequence of "??" with its length\2. So for the example above,  I want to get the following result:

```
mystr = "6374696f6e2022832c12c229"
```

Meaning:

- `????` replaced with `2`
- `??????` replaced with `3`
- `??` replaced with `1`
- `????` replaced with `2`

I tried the following but I'm not sure it's the good approach, and anyway -- it doesn't work:

```
regex = re.compile('(\?+)')
matches = regex.findall(mystr)
if matches:
        for match in matches:
                match_length = len(match)/2
                if (match_length > 0):
                        mystr= regex .sub(match_length , mystr)
```

Comment: Just pass `lambda m: str(len(m.group())//2)` to `re.sub`

Comment: @Rawing Wouldn't that replace `???` with `1`? Not sure that's ok.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, what's the alternative? Replacing it with `1.5`?

Comment: @Rawing Replacing `??` with `1` and leaving the third `?` alone.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Either way, the lambda is fine. If you want to leave odd numbers of question marks alone, you'll have to use a different regex, not a different replacement function. `(?:\?\?)+` should do it.

Comment: Thanks @Rawing, that solved the problem. Will you elaborate this to an answer and explain how the lambda works in this case so I can accept it. Since you were the first to mention the solution

Comment: @apipota Please mark the question as a duplicate. I'm not sure what there is to explain; the duplicate I linked contains a short explanation and a link to the official docs if for some reason you need more information about replacement functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a callback function in Python's [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). FYI [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) are shorthand to create anonymous functions.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##JY7BCsIwEETv@YolpyyWKqlEK0h/xEtb1xpomrBNwX59jHFg5vIGZsIe335pUrIueI7AJITb18hwB2may9m05mVIn7osfe2K9Ph3zlYKpok@uc5Uj94FO5Ni@egOEoUIbJeoMlm3QZViBXPvhmcP7gZ5Rv34TIty9cR@CwrxqBErKCcQU/oC)

```
import re

mystr = "6374696f6e20????28??????2c??2c????29"
regex = re.compile(r"\?+")

print(re.sub(regex, lambda m: str(int(len(m.group())/2)), mystr))
```

There seems to be uncertainty about what should happen in the case of `???`. The above code will result in `1` since it converts to int. Without `int` conversion the result would be `1.0`. If you want to `???` to become `1?` you can use the pattern `(?:\?{2})+` instead.

Comment: There will always be an even amount of `??` characters since it represents bytes. Thanks!